# Apache + Node.js + Socket.IO 環境による動作でSocketエラーが発生

Tags: node.js, apache, websocket

#### Apache + Node.js + Socket.IO 環境による動作でSocketエラーが発生

先日からNode.jsを触りだし、チャット機能を実装したサーバを立てた所、下記事象が発生致しました。

---

80番ポートでApacheを起動させているローカルサーバーに下記のリバースプロキシを設定し、Node.jsサーバーへ接続しております。

**httpd.conf**

```
< Location /server>
ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8124
ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8124/
< /Location>
```

「(hogehoge.com[ドメイン])/server」以下にアクセスした場合、Node.jsで立てたサーバーへアクセスしております

**Node.js - app.js**

```js
var http     = require("http");
var socketio = require("socket.io");
var fs       = require("fs");

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
     res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/html"});
     var output = fs.readFileSync("./index.html", "utf-8");
     res.end(output);
}).listen(process.env.VMC_APP_PORT || 8124);

var io = socketio.listen(server);

io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {

  console.log("Connection");

  // メッセージ送信（送信者にも送られる）
  socket.on("C_to_S_message", function (data) {
    console.log("Sender Send");
    io.sockets.emit("S_to_C_message", {value:data.value});
  });

  // ブロードキャスト（送信者以外の全員に送信）
  socket.on("C_to_S_broadcast", function (data) {
    console.log("BloadCast Send");
    socket.broadcast.emit("S_to_C_message", {value:data.value});
  });

  // 切断したときに送信
  socket.on("disconnect", function () {
//    io.sockets.emit("S_to_C_message", {value:"user disconnected"});
  });
});
```

**Node.js - index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>node.js chat</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://nodejs.lo/server/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  var s = io.connect('http://nodejs.lo/server'); //ローカル

  //サーバから受け取るイベント
  s.on("connect", function () {
    console.log("Connect OK");
  });  // 接続時
  s.on("disconnect", function (client) {
    console.log("Close OK");
  });  // 切断時
  s.on("S_to_C_message", function (data) {
    addMessage(data.value);
  });

  //クライアントからイベント送信（イベント名は自由に設定できます）
  function sendMessage() {
    var msg = $("#message").val(); //取得
    $("#message").val(""); //空白にする
    s.emit("C_to_S_message", {value:msg}); //サーバへ送信
  }

  function sendBroadcast() {
    var msg = $("#message").val(); //取得
    $("#message").val(""); //空白にする
    s.emit("C_to_S_broadcast", {value:msg}); // サーバへ送信
  }

  //jqueryでメッセージを追加
  function addMessage (value,color,size) {
    var msg = value.replace( /[!@$%<>'"&|]/g, '' ); //タグ記号とかいくつか削除
    $("#msg_list").prepend("<div class='msg'>" + msg + "</div>");
  }

  </script>
  <style>
    *{
      font-size:30px;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="msg_list" style="height:300px; overflow:auto;"></div>
  <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="text" class="text" style="width:95%; padding:10px" id="message"/>
    <input type="submit" class="button" style="padding:10px" onclick="sendMessage();" value="みんなに送信" />
    <input type="submit" class="button" style="padding:10px" onclick="sendBroadcast();" value="自分以外に送信" />
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**ブラウザのコンソールに出力されているエラー**

```
GET ttp://nodejs.lo/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1426313600982-0 404 (Not Found)
content.scripts.c.js:11 TableManager::findTables()
socket.io.js:2919 GET ttp://nodejs.lo/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1426313602201-1 404 (Not Found)
socket.io.js:2919 GET ttp://nodejs.lo/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1426313604016-2 404 (Not Found)
socket.io.js:2919 GET ttp://nodejs.lo/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1426313607637-3 404 (Not Found)
socket.io.js:2919 GET ttp://nodejs.lo/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1426313612676-4 404 (Not Found)
```

socket.io.jsのリクエスト先が「/server」以下になっていない為、エラーが出力されていると考えておりますが、socket.io.jsのリクエスト先を調整できる箇所を発見できませんでした。

上記のエラーおよび設定方法に関して心当たりがある方、恐れ入りますがご教示をお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

英語版に同様の質問があったので転載します。
- [How do I get socket.io running for a subdirectory - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896225/how-do-i-get-socket-io-running-for-a-subdirectory)

> ```
> var io = require('socket.io')(httpServer, {path: '/mysubdir/socket.io'});
> ```
>
> のようにlistenしている場合、
>
> ```
> var socket = io.connect('http://www.example.com', {path: "/mysubdir/socket.io"});
> ```
>
> のように指定します。

つまり、今回の場合

サーバー

```js
var io = require('socket.io')(Server, {path: '/server/socket.io'});
```

クライアント

```js
io.connect('http://nodejs.lo',{path:'/server/socket.io'});
```

※質問内のドメインがごちゃごちゃしているようですがコード内に利用されていたドメインに合わせました。  
ところでもちろんApache HTTPDの`proxy_wstunnel_module`はロードしてますよね？

Answer (score 0):

上記の内容を参考にして調整した所、動作致しました。

```js
var io = require('socket.io')(httpServer, {path: '/server/socket.io'});
```

上記のrequireを行った場合

> /hogehoge/nodejs/chat/app.js:2 > var socketio = require("socket.io")
>   var socketio = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {path: '/server/socket.io'});
>   　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　 ^
>   ReferenceError: httpServer is not defined

上記のエラーが出力されたので原因を調査してみます。
※ 上記requireでなくても動作は致しました。

> ところでもちろんApache HTTPDのproxy_wstunnel_moduleはロードしてますよね？

上記のモジュールをロードしておりませんでした。
これから動作環境に取り込んでみます。

Comment: ごめんなさい、httpServerではなくServerでしたね。修正しました。